# React: OG Meta tag. Image is not showing

Tags: reactjs, sharing, og-meta

I have used `react-helmet` for open graph image tags. But FB is not showing any image on link sharing. Does anyone know how to solve this issue without server-side rendering? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm afraid there's no way to solve this without server-side rendering as it depends on how FB's crawlers work. You might want to read up on the suggested approaches here - https://github.com/nfl/react-helmet/issues/26

Comment: Thanks Yangshun Tay, for that link how FB's crawlers work. 
I was wondering if there is a way to show an image from URL. 
like SHARE_LINK?image=image.jpg